# Permutation in C,C++,C# or Objective-C

Tags: recursion, permutation

I am trying to take a number and change it to something like this:

```
Number  Change To       
1       0001A       
2       0002A
3       0003A
4       0001B
5       0002B       
6       0003B
7       0001C
8       0002C
9       0003C       
10      0001AA
11      0002AA
12      0003AA
13      0001AB
14      0002AB
15      0003AB
10      0001AC
11      0002AC
12      0003AC
13      0001BA
14      0002BA
15      0003BA
```

etc…

So Using the Letters 'A','B','C'
And Using the Numbers 1,2,3

Comment: Thanks Wooble, for answering what it isn't. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most of your inputs, the left-most 'digits' appears to be changing fastest, until you get to 12->13 transition, where the *middle* digit changes slowest:

```
1A
2A
3A
...
2AA
3AA
1AB
2AB
...
```

This is definitely awkward and will probably require a lot of extra effort to code than a scheme where the right-most or left-most digit changes fastest is strictly followed:

```
1A
2A
3A
...
2AA
3AA
1BA
2BA
...
```

or

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
11
12
13
1a
1b
1c
21
22
23
...
```

If you must follow exactly the scheme you've given here, then I'd recommend a lookup-table and simply hardcode this scheme into your source:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char table[][5]={"ZERO", "1A", "2A", "3A", "1B", "2B", "3B", "1C", "2C", "3C",
                            "1AA", "2AA", "3AA", "1AB", "2AB", "3AB", "1AC", "2AC", "3AC"};
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        int input=atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("%d\t%s\n", input, table[input]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please don't use this code directly -- I haven't done *any* input validation or array bounds checks.

Of course, I hope you pick a different approach entirely -- this simple codeword substitution works fine for a specific number of inputs, but some day someone might want to input a number greater than you've got in your table. (In this case, when someone wants to convert `19`, it'll fail.)

A more generic approach, [converting between bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_numbering_formats#Converting_between_bases), is an algorithm for converting between any two number bases. In your case, it *could* be converting into base 6 with the digits `1`, `2`, `3`, `A`, `B`, `C` (if you strictly adhere to either a left-most changes fastest or right-most changes fastest approach).